# User upstart session in different window manager wIndow manager

Tags: window-manager, upstart, gnome-session, i3-wm

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and i3 as window manager. After I have logged in to i3, upstart won't find my user jobs under ~/.config/upstart/. How can I make upstart find these config files without having to execute something like `gnome-session`?

Thanks.

edit, one of the jobs starts redshift, here is the config `~/.config/upstar/redshift.conf`:

`respawn
exec redshift -l 59:18`

When i try to start this job with `initctl start redshift`:
`initctl: Unknown job: redshift`

Comment: WWhat jobs are you trying to start with upstart ? We need more information. There is a general discussion, and some helpful suggestions here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394180/foreman-export-upstart-scripts-as-userjob-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: @bodhi.zazen ok I edited so you can see one of the jobs I start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did to get it to work:

```
echo i3 >> /etc/upstart-xsessions
```

Next I added an i3 entry under `/etc/X11/Xsessions.d/99upstart` (I don't know if this was really necessary).

I also needed to have an init config that will start i3, for this you can look for an existing, I used `/usr/share/upstart/sessions/lxsession.conf`.

Done.